# On Country Dropdown Change set value of Textbox inside Wijgrid

Tags: grid, wijmo

I am using Wijmo grid and want get the Currency value of respected Country dropdown used inside wijgrid.
Simply I am able to get the same functionality without Wijgrid but not in case of Wijgrid.
So please do the needful and the code is below inline-
CSHTML code:

```
<td style="border: 1px solid black;">                               
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].IdCountry, new SelectList(Model[i].HCCountry, "Id", "Value"), "-Select-", new { @id = "country", style = "width: 75px;" })
 </td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black;">
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].txt_Currency, new { @id = "currency", style = "width:50px; border: none;" })                               
</td>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(function() {
$('#country').change(function () {
// fetch the newly selected value
var selectedValue = $('#country').val();
// send it as an AJAX request to some controller action
$.post('@Url.Action("~/Application/GetCurrencies")', { value: selectedValue }, function (result) 
{ $('#currency').html(result); });
});
});
```

Thanks & Regards
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the afterCellEdit event of the WijGrid and can get the desired value. You may refer to the following demo implementing custom editors:

http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/?widget=Grid&sample=Custom%20Editors